# How to use each value in column 1 to add comment (NOTE) from 2 different columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a dynamic way to add **Note** in which cell in my **ID column A**. However the comments need to use the information from Column B and C. ex: **ON 01/13/2020, Anne**.
I am not sure how to check how many times each value from **column A**  will appear and use information from **column D and B** to create the comment (NOTE)..

[image: Table]

result I need. All the time the ID number will be the same the comments need to be the same as well.

[image: Result I need]

The code I am using is

```
Sub Cmt_test()

Sheet1.Range("A2").AddComment "On " & Sheet1.Range("D2") & ", " & Sheet1.Range("B2")

End Sub
```

I don't know how I can make it dynamic to get the information all the time the same ID appears. Maybe if I use Loop on **column A** would it be possible that all the time the loop finds the same ID to add the comment using the information from column D and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Write Comments to Each Cell in a Column

```
Option Explicit

Sub addComments()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRowCol As Long = 1 ' or "A"
    Const str1 As String = "On "
    Const str2 As String = ", "
    Dim Cols As Variant: Cols = Array(1, 2, 4)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Vals As Variant: ReDim Vals(UBound(Cols))
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, Cols(0)), _
                           ws.Cells(LastRow, Cols(0)))
    
    ' Write Column Ranges to Arrays.
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        Vals(j) = rng.Offset(, Cols(j) - Cols(0))
    Next j
    
    ' Loop through elements (rows) of Source Array
    ' and write comments to a dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object, Curr As Variant, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(Vals(0))
         Curr = Vals(0)(i, 1)
         If dict(Curr) <> "" Then
             dict(Curr) = dict(Curr) & vbLf & str1 _
               & Format(Vals(2)(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy") & str2 & Vals(1)(i, 1)
         Else
             dict(Curr) = str1 _
               & Format(Vals(2)(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy") & str2 & Vals(1)(i, 1)
         End If
    Next i
     
    ' Write comments from the dictionary to Source Range.
    rng.ClearComments
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        cel.AddComment dict(cel.Value)
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your time. I am getting a Run-Time error '1004' on Application-defined or object-defined error in this line ` cel.AddComment dict(cel.Value)`

Comment: The first section of the code contains various constants. Have you checked that they fit your setup?

Comment: Yes, I am using F8 and breakpoints to check all the lines and values. Until `next i` everything seems to be okay with the value I need. Howevry `' Write comments from the dictionary to Source Range.
    rng.ClearComments
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        cel.AddComment dict(cel.Value)
    Next cel` all the value appear empty **_dict(cel.value)=Empty_**

Comment: Try adding after `Next i` the following lines: `Debug.Print ws.Name: Debug.Print rng.Address: Debug.Print dict.Count: Debug.Print UBound(Vals(0))` and get back with the results from the Immediate window (CTRL+G). If a line errors out, just uncomment it.

Comment: Seems like the Vals (variants) as subscript out of range after they finish the loop until last row

Comment: I used the `Debug.Print ws.Name: Debug.Print rng.Address: Debug.Print dict.Count: Debug.Print UBound(Vals(0))` 
the sheet is correct, 
rng.address is correct (from row 2 until last row
the dict.count is showing 6 (this may be wrong) 
Ubound(Vals(0) is showing lastrow -1

Comment: I did, I changed, in my original data the sheet name is FIS.
column with ID is Column D (4).
Columns with Person name is G (7) 
column with date is J (10)

Comment: I did So you have to change Array(4, 7, 10) and the LastRowCol to 4, and wsName to "FIS".. I will check the file and try again. However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I found the error, sorry. Change to `Vals(j) = rng.Offset(, Cols(j) - Cols(0))`.

Comment: A quick question. If I would like the Comment Note to appear on column C (3) could I just change this party ` Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, Cols(0)), _
                           ws.Cells(LastRow, Cols(0)))`

I will still use the information from columns 4, 7, 10, however the comment would be placed on column C

Comment: In the constants section add `Const CommentCol As Long = 3`.
Then before `rng.ClearComments` add the following line:
`Set rng = rng.Offset(, CommentCol - Cols(0))`.